# X and Y values when using CIDetector

Tags: ios, swift, camera, core-image, cidetector

So i have my code posted below and it seems to be detecting faces properly. As i was attempting to build a rectangle around the detected face i saw the options for `.bounds.origin.x` and `.bounds.origin.y` and I had a few questions i was hoping that you guys could help me answer:

background: I have an image view that displays the `AVVideoOutput` with the CIDetector working on the image view.

1. Are the x and y points for the middle of the face that the CIDetector has found? or is it the distance of the face from the parent view's x & y? or is it the relationship of the detected face to the center of the image view?
2. What is the layout of the x and y plane that the values are being drawn from? (For example if the detected face is in the bottom right of the front camera the values for x and y are smaller, close to 0 even)
3. Is the plane(s) documented somewhere?
4. can this plane be manipulated or is it standard?
5. are there positive and negatives because I haven't found any?
6. are these values/ is this plane ever subject to changing if the camera moves or are the values changing entirely due to the center of the detected face?

Thank you for any help or documentation posted! I'll be searching as well but i was hoping someone could help out cause I haven't found much considering I (obviously) don't really know what I am asking for...

Comment: Have you looked at the `metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:` and related methods on AVCaptureOutput?